# How to take int and double as input but not a char?

Tags: c, input, scanf

I'm trying to make a while loop that will be used to take an `int` and a `double` as input. But sometimes there could be a `char` in the input which I want to skip, and then continue the loop.

This will skip the loop and I want to still use the scanf:

```
scanf("%d%lf", &num,&n_double);
while((num != 'a')&&(n_double != 'a'))
```

Comment: How about reading the whole line, and then try to parse that using e.g. [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)? Remember to check what `sscanf` returns.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by that?

Comment: Something like `while (fgets(...) != NULL) { if (sscanf(...) == 2) { /* all okay */ } else { /* error parsing */ } }`

Comment: Is it possible to completely ignore if it's wrong and continue inputting? My apologizes if the question is a bit low level.

Comment: Yes, no `else` case in the code-snippet in my previous comment, then the loop will just continue to read the next line.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still having difficult time to understand, If my input isn't a string what do I use fgets?

Comment: That's kind of the point. You read it as a string, and then try to parse the string you have instead of trying to parse the input directly which will lead to problems when there's invalid input.

Comment: ...it is easier to just move on to read another string, than to try to get past invalid input, which does not go away when you are reading directly.

Comment: Input always is read as `char`. You mean a _character_ you want to skip. Please differentiate betwee these two: different abstractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First read the whole line, then use [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to parse the input line into an integer and a double. If, however parsing fails to give an int and a double, conclude that as the error case, i.e. a char present in the line.

You can try this code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char line[100];
    while(fgets(line, 100, stdin)) {
        int i;
        double d;
        if(sscanf(line, "%d %lf", &i, &d) == 2) {
            printf("%d %lf\n", i, d);
        }
        else {
            printf("wrong input!\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Edited as per comment:

from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

> **`char *fgets( char *str, int count, FILE *stream );`**
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `str` - pointer to an element of a char array
>
> `count` - maximum number of characters to write (typically the length
>   of str)
>
> `stream` - file stream to read the data from
>
> **Return value**
>
> `str` on success, `null` pointer on failure.

So, `while(fgets(str...))` translates to "while `fgets` doesn't return null", which translates to "while fgets continues to successfully read the input stream (which in this case is `stdin`, the standard input)".

Please take a look at the documentation for further clarification.

Comment: No no no no! Don't use `gets`! Never use `gets`! Don't tell anyone to use `gets`! It's dangerous, and will lead to serious security problems. Besides, it has been deprecated since the C99 standard and removed from the C11 standard.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ok, what can I use instead? But I have been using `gets` from the very beginning of my learning C :( I have changed to scanf, is it ok to use that?

Comment: [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is the usual replacement. As for why it's bad, think about someone entering an input that is longer than the 99 characters allowed by your 100 character array (remember one character is needed for the string terminator).

Comment: @Joachim I have changed my code already, thanks to you! Will remember that advice of yours :D

Comment: Worked like a charm, you're my hero!       If I can ask what do this line mean? :" while(fgets(line, 100, stdin))"?

Comment: @Dannz Edited to add a little explanation for that while loop conditional. Also, take a look at the docs Joachim referred to. Here is the [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) again. Check the edit history to see another technique using `scanf` to take whole line input. Finally, please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you!

Comment: For the future readers who might be wondering why @Joachim was so freaked out ;) about using `gets()`, take a look at [this](http://bugsniffer.blogspot.com/2007/11/infamous-software-failures.html). Look at the fourth one, the one about Buffer overflow! This is just one example I stumbled upon today; I am sure Joachim can cite many more :D

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean input validation?

```
char line[80];
int ival;
double dval;

fgets(line, 80, stdin);

if (sscanf(line, "%d", &ival) == 1)
    /* got an int */
else if (sscanf(line, "%f", &dval) == 1)
    /* got a double */
else
    fprintf(stderr, "Not int nor double\n");
```

Comment: The logic is a little flawed, the error message can be printed even if an integer was read first.

Comment: added `else if` @JoachimPileborg